# copying a std::string to a char* (for TCP/IP sockets)

Tags: c++, arrays, string, qt4, dynamic-memory-allocation

I decided to redo the question to clarify it,
Im currently working on a school project where im creating a client server with TCP/IP sockets, now im not having an issue with these its related....

right now i have a helper function it will take in a pointer to the socket and some data i will be sending to the server, it will build a std::string in the exactly format i want the characters to be then convert it to a character array and send it to the server

```
buffer = new char[tempBuffer.size()];
cout << tempBuffer.size() << " ++ " << strlen(buffer) << " ++ " << endl;
strcpy(buffer, tempBuffer.c_str());
cout << buffer << "  " << tempBuffer.size() << " ++ " << strlen(buffer) << " ++" << endl;
write (*socket, buffer, strlen(buffer));
delete [] buffer;
```

-tempBuffer is a std::string i build earlier in the helper function we dont need to worry about that i know that part works fine

now this all appears to work perfectly when i run it in my function main() i can send as much between the client and server as i would like however when i use it into a UI class and use it i get a really long glibc error why would this be?

Comment: If you're preparing a buffer for data transmission and you're *not* using a `std::vector<unsigned char>` and some very meticulous serialization (or just using a serialization library) you're not thinking deep enough. You don't want to send formatted data; you want to send *raw* data, in a specific form for it to be reconstructible client-side. There are good reasons for serialization protocols, and you would do well to consider them.

Comment: Why not just use `.c_str()` directly in the `write` like this? `write(*socket, tempBuffer.c_str(), tempBuffer.size());` Seems a whole lot easier...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cout << *buffer << "  " << tempBuffer.size() << " ++ " << sizeof(*buffer) << " ++" << endl;
```

This is wrong for two reasons. First, `buffer` is not a C-style string. It's just arbitrary data. So you can't pass it to `operator << (char *)` (because that's for strings, how would it know how many bytes to output?). Second, `sizeof(*buffer)` is 1, since `buffer` is a `char *` (how could it possibly know the size?).

You have to manage the size yourself. You can't expect `operator<<` or `sizeof` to magically know how many bytes you care about. You can't treat `buffer` as a string, it's just an array of characters.

Comment: +1, As we cannot see it, there is no way to know for sure, but I believe `buffer` is a `char **`. From what I see, specifically that `strcpy()`, it is the only way this will even compile. And if so, then `sizeof(*buffer)` is the size of a pointer; not 1. That said, the premise of this answer is still absolutely correct (same issue, just a 4 or 8 rather than 1), and the OP would do well to digest it carefully.

Comment: ok then my confusion arises from the cout works perfectly fine the buffer that i want lets say "Client: Instructor, " is output, and sizof(*buffer) outputs 4 not 1, in fact when i send the data to the server its all sent fine it can output it all it looks exactly as it should the exact length I want it to be, and if i was to declare a character array and call sizeof(thatArray) i would get the size i set it to when i defined it, also isn't the name 'thatArray' really a pointer to the first element of a list of characters? how is that any different than my dynamically allocated list of chars?

Comment: Oh, buffer is a `char **`, so `*buffer` is a `char *` and pointers are four bytes on your platform. The difference is that your dynamically allocated list of characters is not a C object. The only C object is a *pointer* to it. The size of the pointer is four bytes on your platform. Since it points to a character, the size of what it points to is the size of a character. There exists no language object whose size is the number of bytes you allocated, so there's nothing you can pass to `sizeof`.

Comment: i gotcha! yeah ive been using a hack around it knowing in c++ a character is one byte i can call strlen and work with that however the error is in my main function when i call delete [] buffer (its the main function so its just a pointer here) i get a very large glibc error

Comment: No, the problem is that you want `delete [] (*buffer);`. You need to pass to `delete[]` *exactly* what you got from `new[]`. You should have just made `buffer` a `char *`, so you wouldn't have use `*buffer` everywhere. (Any time you see `*foo` every place you use `foo`, that should be an indication that you used the wrong type in the first place.)

Comment: actually buffer is declared as char *buffer, i then send it into a helper function as a double pointer so i can allocated memory to that pointer for my buffering, then outside the helper function i call delete[] buffer; after i send the buffer over to my server, the little code snipet i show is for my helper function that builds my buffer form a string i build

Comment: it now occurs to my it may be best to send data to the sever then delete it all within the same helper function, hopefully that will help